# Show always the last line in a TextArea

Tags: java, javafx-8

I have a JavaFx TextArea where i update the text from another thread.

```
/**
     * Start a new thread to update the text in the textarea. The progressmanager is called in a loop to deleiver the updated text
     */
    private void startTextAreaUpdate() {

        final Task<Void> updateTextAreaTask = new Task<Void>() {

            @Override
            protected Void call() throws Exception {

                // Start updating the progresstext
                while (!prog.getIsDone()) {
                    updateMessage(prog.getProgressText());
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                }

                return null;

            }

        };

        //Here the TextArea text is bound to the task
        taProgressText.textProperty()
                .bind(updateTextAreaTask.messageProperty());
        // Start the action in a new thread
        Thread th = new Thread(updateTextAreaTask);
        th.setDaemon(true);
        th.start();

    }
```

Because the text doesn't fit in the textarea i always want to show the last line of the text.
In the main thread i add a ChangeListener.

```
taProgressText.textProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {

    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> observable,
            String oldValue, String newValue) {
        int lastPos = taProgressText.getText().length();
        taProgressText.positionCaret(lastPos);
    }
});
```

However the position doesn't change. What is going wrong here?

Comment: Not really related to your question but you don't show the implementation of the updateMessage method. I think that needs to run on the FX Application Thread.

Comment: @Boomah [`updateMessage`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Task.html#updateMessage-java.lang.String-) is part of the Task API, "Calls to updateMessage are coalesced and run later on the FX application thread".

Answer (score 0):

I think the position of the carat changes, but it doesn't actually scroll.
Try this (ugly hack...) instead of the binding and the current listener you have:

```
updateTextAreaTask.messageProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> obs, String oldMessage, String newMessage) {
        taProgressText.setText(newMessage);
        ScrollBar scrollBar = (ScrollBar) taProgressText.lookup(".scroll-bar:vertical");
        if (scrollBar != null) {
            scrollBar.setValue(scrollBar.getMax());
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't work. I suspect a bug when you update the TextArea from another thread. I also tried setScrollTop(Double.MAX_VALUE) and setScrollTop(Double.MIN_VALUE). When i debug the listner is triggered but nothin happens with the scrollbar.

Comment: It's not updating on another thread: this will run on the FX Application Thread. It worked for me, but working with lookups like this is not very robust.